# Haskell parser to AST data type, assignment

Tags: parsing, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I have been searching around the interwebs for a couple of days, trying to get an answer to my questions and i'm finally admitting defeat.
I have been given a grammar:

`Dig ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9

 Int ::= Dig | Dig Int

 Var ::= a | b | ... z | A | B | C | ... | Z

 Expr ::= Int | - Expr | + Expr Expr | * Expr Expr | Var | let Var = Expr in Expr`

And i have been told to parse, evaluate and print expressions using this grammar
where the operators `* + -` has their normal meaning
The specific task is to write a function `parse :: String -> AST`

that takes a string as input and returns an abstract syntax tree when the input is in the correct format (which i can asume it is).

I am told that i might need a suitable data type and that data type might need to derive from some other classes.

Following an example output
`data AST = Leaf Int | Sum AST AST | Min AST | ...`

Further more, i should consider writing a function
`tokens::String -> [String]`
to split the input string into a list of tokens
Parsing should be accomplished with
 `ast::[String] -> (AST,[String])`
where the input is a list of tokens and it outputs an AST, and to parse sub-expressions i should simply use the ast function recursively.

I should also make a printExpr method to print the result so that
`printE: AST -> String`
`printE(parse "* 5 5")` yields either `"5*5"` or `"(5*5)"`
and also a function to evaluate the expression
`evali :: AST -> Int`

I would just like to be pointed in the right direction of where i might start. I have little knowledge of Haskell and FP in general and trying to solve this task i made some string handling function out of Java which made me realize that i'm way off track.
So a little pointer in the right direction, and maybe an explantion to 'how' the AST should look like
Third day in a row and still no running code, i really appreciate any attempt to help me find a solution!
Thanks in advance!
  **Edit**

I might have been unclear:
I'm wondering how i should go about from having read and tokenized an input string to making an AST.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read about ASTs, then read a Haskell tutorial, then post an actual question if you're still stuck.

Comment: thank you for you reply. i have read about haskell and several tutorials including some conserning parsing. i wouldnt care to ask if i hadnt. what i don't understand is how to start writing a function that returns an AST, my book 'programming in Haskell' doesnt mention it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Parsing tokens into an Abstract Syntax Tree

OK, let's take your grammar

```
Dig ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
Int ::= Dig | Dig Int
Var ::= a | b | ... z | A | B | C | ... | Z
Expr ::= Int | - Expr | + Expr Expr | * Expr Expr | Var | let Var = Expr in Expr
```

This is a nice easy grammar, because you can tell from the first token what sort of epression it will be.
(If there was something more complicated, like `+` coming between numbers, or `-` being used for subtraction as 
well as negation, you'd need the list-of-successes trick, explained in 
[Functional Parsers](http://roman-dushkin.narod.ru/files/fp__jeroen_fokker_001.pdf).)

Let's have some sample raw input:

```
rawinput = "- 6 + 45 let x = - 5 in * x x"
```

Which I understand from the grammar represents `"(- 6 (+ 45 (let x=-5 in (* x x))))"`, 
and I'll assume you tokenised it as

```
tokenised_input' = ["-","6","+","4","5","let","x","=","-","5","in","*","x","x"]
```

which fits the grammar, but you might well have got

```
tokenised_input = ["-","6","+","45","let","x","=","-","5","in","*","x","x"]
```

which fits your sample `AST` better. I think it's good practice to name your AST after bits of your grammar, 
so I'm going to go ahead and replace

```
data AST = Leaf Int | Sum AST AST | Min AST | ...
```

with

```
data Expr = E_Int Int | E_Neg Expr | E_Sum Expr Expr | E_Prod Expr Expr | E_Var Char 
                      | E_Let {letvar::Char,letequal:: Expr,letin::Expr}
 deriving Show
```

I've named the bits of an `E_Let` to make it clearer what they represent.

### Writing a parsing function

You could use `isDigit` by adding `import Data.Char (isDigit)` to help out:

```
expr :: [String] -> (Expr,[String])
expr [] = error "unexpected end of input"
expr (s:ss) | all isDigit s = (E_Int (read s),ss)
             | s == "-" = let (e,ss') = expr ss in (E_Neg e,ss') 
             | s == "+" = (E_Sum e e',ss'') where
                          (e,ss') = expr ss
                          (e',ss'') = expr ss'
            -- more cases
```

Yikes! Too many let clauses obscuring the meaning, 
and we'll be writing the same code for `E_Prod` and very much worse for `E_Let`.
Let's get this sorted out!

The standard way of dealing with this is to write some combinators;
instead of tiresomely threading the input `[String]`s through our definition, define ways to 
mess with the output of parsers (map) and combine
multiple parsers into one (lift).

### Clean up the code 1: map

First we should define `pmap`, our own equivalent of the `map` function so we can do `pmap E_Neg (expr1 ss)`
instead of `let (e,ss') = expr1 ss in (E_Neg e,ss')`

```
pmap :: (a -> b) -> ([String] -> (a,[String])) -> ([String] -> (b,[String]))
```

nonono, I can't even read that! We need a type synonym:

```
type Parser a = [String] -> (a,[String])

pmap :: (a -> b) -> Parser a -> Parser b
pmap f p = \ss -> let (a,ss') = p ss 
                  in (f a,ss')
```

But really this would be better if I did

```
data Parser a = Par [String] -> (a,[String])
```

so I could do

```
instance Functor Parser where
  fmap f (Par p) = Par (pmap f p)
```

I'll leave that for you to figure out if you fancy.

### Clean up the code 2: combining two parsers

We also need to deal with the situation when we have two parsers to run, 
and we want to combine their results using a function. This is called lifting the function to parsers.

```
liftP2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser c
liftP2 f p1 p2 = \ss0 -> let
              (a,ss1) = p1 ss0
              (b,ss2) = p2 ss1
              in (f a b,ss2)
```

or maybe even three parsers:

```
liftP3 :: (a -> b -> c -> d) -> Parser a -> Parser b -> Parser c -> Parser d
```

I'll let you think how to do that.
In the let statement you'll need `liftP5` to parse the sections of a let statement, 
lifting a function that ignores the `"="` and `"in"`. You could make

```
equals_ :: Parser ()
equals_ [] = error "equals_: expected = but got end of input"
equals_ ("=":ss) = ((),ss)
equals_ (s:ss) = error $ "equals_: expected = but got "++s
```

and a couple more to help out with this.

Actually, `pmap` could also be called `liftP1`, but map is the traditional name for that sort of thing.

### Rewritten with the nice combinators

Now we're ready to clean up `expr`:

```
expr :: [String] -> (Expr,[String])
expr [] = error "unexpected end of input"
expr (s:ss) | all isDigit s = (E_Int (read s),ss)
            | s == "-" = pmap   E_Neg expr ss
            | s == "+" = liftP2 E_Sum expr expr ss
            -- more cases
```

That'd all work fine. Really, it's OK. But `liftP5` is going to be a bit long, and feels messy.

### Taking the cleanup further - the ultra-nice Applicative way

Applicative Functors is the way to go. 
Remember I suggested refactoring as

```
data Parser a = Par [String] -> (a,[String])
```

so you could make it an instance of `Functor`? Perhaps you don't want to, 
because all you've gained is a new name `fmap` for the perfectly working `pmap` and
you have to deal with all those `Par` constructors cluttering up your code.
Perhaps this will make you reconsider, though; we can `import Control.Applicative`, 
then using the `data` declaration, we can 
define `<*>`, which sort-of means `then` and use `<$>` instead of `pmap`, with `*>` meaning
`<*>-but-forget-the-result-of-the-left-hand-side` so you would write

```
expr (s:ss) | s == "let" = E_Let <$> var *> equals_ <*> expr <*> in_ *> expr
```

Which looks a lot like your grammar definition, so it's easy to write code that works first time.
This is how I like to write Parsers. In fact, it's how I like to write an awful lot of things.
You'd only have to define `fmap`, `<*>` and `pure`, all simple ones, and no long repetative `liftP3`, `liftP4` etc.

Read up about Applicative Functors. They're great.

- [Applicative in Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids)
- [Applicative in Haskell wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_Functors)

Hints for making Parser applicative: `pure` doesn't change the list. 
`<*>` is like `liftP2`, but the function doesn't come from outside, it comes as the output from `p1`.

Answer (score 4):

To make a start with Haskell itself, I'd recommend [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), a very well-written and entertaining guide. [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) is another oft-recommended starting point.

Edit: A more fundamental introduction to parsing is [Functional Parsers](http://roman-dushkin.narod.ru/files/fp__jeroen_fokker_001.pdf). I wanted *How to replace a failure by a list of successes* by PHilip Wadler. Sadly, it doesn't seem to be available online.

To make a start with parsing in Haskell, I think you should first read [monadic parsing in Haskell](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/223/1/pearl.pdf), then maybe [this wikibook example](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Practical_monads#Parsing_monads), but also then the [parsec guide](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/parsec/parsec.html).

Your grammar

```
Dig ::= 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
Int ::= Dig | Dig Int
Var ::= a | b | ... z | A | B | C | ... | Z
Expr ::= Int | - Expr | + Expr Expr | * Expr Expr | Var | let Var = Expr in Expr
```

suggests a few abstract data types:

```
data Dig = Dig_0 | Dig_1 | Dig_2 | Dig_3 | Dig_4 | Dig_5 | Dig_6 | Dig_7 | Dig_8 | Dig_9
data Integ = I_Dig Dig | I_DigInt Dig Integ
data Var = Var_a | Var_b | ... Var_z | Var_A | Var_B | Var_C | ... | Var_Z
data Expr = Expr_I Integ 
          | Expr_Neg Expr
          | Expr_Plus Expr Expr
          | Expr_Times Expr Expr Var
          | Expr_Var Var
          | Expr_let Var Expr Expr
```

This is inherently a recursively defined syntax tree, no need to make another one.
Sorry about the clunky `Dig_` and `Integ_` stuff - they have to start with an uppercase.

(Personally I'd want to be converting the `Integ`s to `Int`s straight away, so would have done `newtype Integ = Integ Int`, and would probably have done `newtype Var = Var Char` but that might not suit you.)

Once you've done with the basic ones - `dig` and `var`, and `neg_`, `plus_`, `in_` etcI'd go with the Applicative interface to build them up, so for example your parser `expr` for `Expr` would be something like

```
expr =        Expr_I <$> integ 
          <|> Expr_Neg <$> neg_ *> expr
          <|> Expr_Plus <$> plus_ *> expr <*> expr
          <|> Expr_Times <$> times_ *> expr <*> expr
          <|> Expr_Var <$> var
          <|> Expr_let <$> let_ *> var <*> equals_ *> expr <*> in_ *> expr
```

So nearly all the time, your Haskell code is clean and closely resembles the grammar you were given.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i will check it out and come back to you. I dont think i'm supposed to use parsec, though.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it seems you're trying to build lots and lots of stuff, and you're not really sure exactly where it's all going. I would suggest that getting the definition for `AST` right, and then trying to implement `evali` would be a good start.

The grammer you've listed is interesting... You seem to want to input `* 5 5`, but output `5*5`, whic is an odd choice. Is that really supposed to be a unary minus, not binary? Simlarly, `* Expr Expr Var` looks like perhaps you might have meant to type `* Expr Expr | Var`...

Anyway, making some assumptions about what you meant to say, your AST is going to look something like this:

```
data AST = Leaf Int | Sum AST AST | Minus AST | Var String | Let String AST AST
```

Now, let us try to do `printE`. It takes an AST and gives us a string. By the definition above, the AST has to be one of five possible things. You just need to figure out what to print for each one!

```
 printE :: AST -> String
 printE (Leaf  x  ) = show x
 printE (Sum   x y) = printE x ++ " + " ++ printE y
 printE (Minus x  ) = "-" ++ printE x
 ...
```

`show` turns an `Int` into a `String`. `++` joins two strings together. I'll let you work out the rest of the function. (The tricky thing is if you want it to print brackets to correctly show the order of subexpressions... Since your grammer doesn't mention brackets, I guess no.)

Now, how about `evali`? Well, this is going to be a similar deal. If the AST is a `Leaf x`, then `x` is an `Int`, and you just return that. If you have, say, `Minus x`, then `x` isn't an integer, it's an AST, so you need to turn it into an integer with `evali`. The function looks something like

```
evali :: AST -> Int
evali (Leaf  x  ) = x
evali (Sum   x y) = (evali x) + (evali y)
evali (Minus x  ) = 0 - (evali x)
...
```

That works great so far. But wait! It looks like you're supposed to be able to use `Let` to define new variables, and refer to them later with `Var`. Well, in that case, you need to *store* those variables somewhere. And that's going to make the function more complicated.

My recommendation would be to use `Data.Map` to store a list of variable names and their corresponding values. You'll need to add the variable map to a type signature. You can do it this way:

```
evali :: AST -> Int
evali ast = evaluate Data.Map.empty ast

evaluate :: Map String Int -> AST -> Int
evaluate m ast =
  case ast of
    ...same as before...
    Let var ast1 ast2 -> evaluate (Data.Map.insert var (evaluate m ast1)) ast2
    Var var           -> m ! var
```

So `evali` now just calls `evaluate` with an empty variable map. When `evaluate` sees `Let`, it adds the variable to the map. And when it sees `Var`, it looks up the name in the map.

As for *parsing* a string into an AST in the first place, that is an entire *other* answer again...

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful! I might have some further questions regarding parsing a string into an ast, but for now i am deeply grateful!

Comment: Well-formed questions are always welcome on SO. I know it can be kinda hard when you're like "hell, I don't even know exactly what I'm trying to do". Hopefully as the task becomes clearer to you, you'll be able to pinpoint exactly what you need help with better.

Comment: That mapping function was brilliant!