# Haskell - execute basic prefix operations from input

Tags: parsing, haskell, matching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell parser to AST data type, assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712149/haskell-parser-to-ast-data-type-assignment)

I'm stuck on a problem and I've been for some time now. I got a string table with the intention of calculating a series of Int values with the prefix operators that are entered as an input along with the numbers.

The idea is to write i.e. "+ 3 * 2 4" in the console and have it calculate 3 + (2*4), then outputting the answer. I'm fairly new to Haskell and I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

I've made some code to parse the string as a string table with each numbers and operators as a single elements in the string table import Data.Char

```
    import Data.Char

    data AST = Leaf Int | Sum AST AST | Min AST | Mult AST AST

    parseCharacter :: String -> [String]
    parseCharacter [] = []
    parseCharacter (' ':xs) = parseCharacter xs
    parseCharacter ('(':xs) = "(": parseCharacter xs
    parseCharacter (')':xs) = ")": parseCharacter xs
    parseCharacter ('+':xs) = "+": parseCharacter xs
    parseCharacter ('-':xs) = "-": parseCharacter xs
    parseCharacter ('*':xs) = "*": parseCharacter xs
    parseCharacter (x:xs) = if isDigit x then (takeWhile isDigit (x:xs)) : parseCharacter (dropWhile isDigit xs) else parseCharacter xs
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712149/haskell-parser-to-ast-data-type-assignment ?

Comment: What you want to do is first create a list of tokens (lexical analysis) - which is what you're doing already - and then parse that list of tokens to a AST or a number (depending on what you need). Understanding Monads can be quite useful for both tasks (although in this case your function works just fine for the tokenizing part).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That link is surprisingly relevant! I'll check out Monads, thanks again.